# Error encountered during model fitting for Image multi_classification : SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I keep getting this syntax error even after I tried changing lots of argument positions.
What is wrong with the validation_datagen line?

```
history = model.fit_generator(train_datagen.flow(training_images, training_labels, batch_size=10),
                          epochs=10,
                          validation_datagen.flow(testing_images, testing_labels, batch_size=10))
model.evaluate(testing_images, testing_labels, verbose=0)
```

> File "", line 22
>       validation_datagen.flow(testing_images, testing_labels, batch_size=10))
>       ^ SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: Put your validation_datagen before epochs. Or specify that validation_data=validation_datagen. When assigning a keyword argument in Python, those should go after the parameters that don't have a default value.

Comment: thank you, that was problem